# How to getValueAt(int ,int) Listbox on zkoss like JTable in Swing

Tags: java, zk

I want to export data from `listbox` to `excel` file,but my problem is How to do `getValueAt(int,int)` in `zkoss` like the following code.

```
int j = start;
            for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
                for (j = start; j < col; j++) {
                    Object row2=model.getValueAt(i,j);
                    String str = (row2 == null ? "" : row2.toString());  
                    //INI untuk memulai write ke file dari kolom ke berapa dan row ke berapa
                    Label row = new Label(j, i +1,str); 
                    //INI untuk auto size cellnya
                    for(int x=0;x<model.getColumnCount();x++){
                    sheet1.setColumnView(x,30);
                    }
                    row.setCellFormat(formatRow);
                    sheet1.addCell(row);
                }
            }
```

Please help.

Comment: do you need to export the complete listbox as it shown on screen?

Comment: yess exactly, how to do that?? please help

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually this could be a lot easier then you think.

There is a project called [ZK Exporter](https://github.com/samchuang/exporter).
The following code (MVVM) is all you need to do when using this project :

```
@Command
public void exportListboxToExcel(@BindingParam("ref") Listbox listbox) throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    ExcelExporter exporter = new ExcelExporter();
    exporter.export(listbox, out);

    AMedia amedia = new AMedia("FirstReport.xlsx", "xls", "application/file", out.toByteArray());
    Filedownload.save(amedia);
    out.close();
}
```

If you want to read more about it, there is a [complete small talk](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2012/December/Export_Grid_or_Listbox_to_PDF_or_Excel) about it.
I personally did some changes on the awesome project, if you need them just ask it.

Mine changes are :

- Listcell with multiple labels export now also, the original project get blanks.
- checkboxes also exports to value TRUE/FALSE, original project get blanks.